# Can I use `DataTable.Select(filterString)` to control the displayed rows and also use `DataGridView.Sort()` to control the order they're displayed in?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

If I write:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable.Select(fitlerString);
myDataGridView.Sort(myDataGridView.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message

```
"DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted."
```

but I can't find a way to get a Datatable (instead of a `DataRow[]`) with only the desired rows out of the `DataTable.Select()` call.

Can I use `DataTable.Select(filterString)` to control the displayed rows in a DataGridView and also use `DataGridView.Sort()` to control the order they're displayed in? 
If it's not going to cause problems elsewhere I'd prefer to be able to keep my DataSource as a DataTable to avoid having to change assumptions elsewhere in the codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to suffle around your data.  Good news is I found this [blog entry](http://wessamzeidan.net/cs/blog/archive/2006/03/04/371.aspx) by Wessam Zeidan which has the code already written.  The problem he is solving is just a bit different but I think it will help you.  The main take-away is converting the DataRow[] object back into a DataTable. Be sure to read the comments as well as they may help.

Good luck and Good sorting!

Comment: Looking at the comments it appears I don't need to do any conversion.  myDataTable.DefaultView.Filter = filterString appears to do what I need without the overhead of copying large numbers of rows.